# Terminology (analogy?) for losing control of a secret due to re-sharing

Tags: access-control, terminology

Regarding sharing a password/access/secret to someone... and then you don't have control whether they will also share this on, and potentially it could/will end up publicly known, thus insecure.

The term I am looking for is along the lines of "chinese whispers" but that means "the message gets more distorted"... I want the phrase depicting that a recipient can potentially just keep sharing the secret down a chain:

> Okay Joe: Hicsy said this password is really secret so just type it once and forget it.
>
> > Hi Marie, I shouldn't even have this password so, i'm only sharing it just this once to you + Sue
> >
> > > Hi guys, here's that password that you use to unlock devices in evidence room.
> > >
> > > > WareZ/SecureBoot_Backdoor.txt

Comment: If you willingly share the password with someone, it can be called delegation/transfer of right based on whether you keep the control as well or not. If you share the password and someone else takes it from you, well let's just call it breach of trust

Answer (score -1):

It's called "the game of broken telephone", and was pulled on us in grade school. The teacher tells the left front pupil something, everone passes it on, and the right rear pupil says what they heard. It's hilarious!